# How do make a node server application that receives email?

Tags: node.js, email

There are dedicated modules for sending email, such as `nodemailer`. Or for building an email *client* using IMAP.

I need a lightweight email *server* node application on a dedicated domain with an MX record so that the app can receive emails on it's own; not just logging in to a pre-existing email server.

Does a library exist for this purpose? Preferably one that supports Opportunistic TLS over port 465, as an addition to default port 25 for MX.

The only relevant mention I have come across is [mailin.io](http://mailin.io/). However, this domain has been offline since I'm trying to check it out, and the [repository](https://github.com/Flolagale/mailin) seems very outdated, so I am calling this "Plan C" and haven't researched if this is a viable solution. I'm looking for a "Plan A" and a "Plan B" first.

Comment: maybe use a open-source node smtp server or write your custom one that supports a minimal required subset of the protocol so it satisfies your needs? - https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc821

Comment: I would love using an open-souce SMTP server that is able to _receive_ mail on it's own. I haven't successfully found one.

Comment: did you check Haraka? https://github.com/haraka/Haraka